# Angular 8 update - build production failed

Tags: angular

I have an issue with the production build of my Angular App after upgrading from 7 to 8.

I don't know what is really the problem. The error is unclear for me. Do you have any ideas on how to solve my issue?

Error:

```
   ERROR in src/__ng_typecheck__.ts(334,62): error TS2344: Type '"enabled" | "minRows" | "maxRows" | "cdkAutosizeMinRows" | "cdkAutosizeMaxRows" | "matAutosizeMinRows" | "matAutosizeMaxRows" | "matAutosize" | "matTextareaAutosize"' does not satisfy the constraint '"ngOnDestroy" | "ngDoCheck" | "enabled" | "reset" | "ngAfterViewInit" | "minRows" | "maxRows" | "matAutosizeMinRows" | "matAutosizeMaxRows" | "matAutosize" | "matTextareaAutosize" | "_setMinHeight" | "_setMaxHeight" | "resizeToFitContent" | "_noopInputHandler"'.
  Type '"cdkAutosizeMinRows"' is not assignable to type '"ngOnDestroy" | "ngDoCheck" | "enabled" | "reset" | "ngAfterViewInit" | "minRows" | "maxRows" | "matAutosizeMinRows" | "matAutosizeMaxRows" | "matAutosize" | "matTextareaAutosize" | "_setMinHeight" | "_setMaxHeight" | "resizeToFitContent" | "_noopInputHandler"'.
```

Build:

```
"optimization": true,
"outputHashing": "all",
"sourceMap": true,
"extractCss": true,
"namedChunks": false,
"aot": true,
"extractLicenses": true,
"vendorChunk": false,
"buildOptimizer": true,
```

build command:

```
 ng build --prod --configuration=my-prod-build
```

Package

```
Angular CLI: 8.0.1
Node: 12.4.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 8.0.0
... animations, cdk, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, material, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.800.1
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.800.1
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.800.1
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.800.1
@angular-devkit/core              8.0.1
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.6.8
@angular/cli                      8.0.1
@angular/http                     8.0.0-beta.10
@ngtools/webpack                  8.0.1
@schematics/angular               8.0.1
@schematics/update                0.800.1
rxjs                              6.5.2
typescript                        3.4.5
webpack                           4.30.0
```

Comment: Do you have the same error with `ng serve`?

Comment: nope, ng serve is fine

Comment: I tried to reproduce but I've no error using `cdkAutosizeMinRows` with the same configuration.